# Get product title by given permalink , Woocomerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

i'm working a Woocommerce site , and trying to get product title by given Permalink . i know how to get the product permalink by given title here :

```
$product = get_page_by_title( 'Product Title', OBJECT, 'product' );
echo get_permalink( $product->ID );
```

But i can't find a way to get product title by given Permalink ;

Please help ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a permalink that is :http://localhost/11New_plugin_Woo/?product=women-glasses3

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce is act as custom post type, so you can get the details of a products as like the post

so try

```
get_the_title($product->ID)
```

to get the title of the proudcts

```
get_permalink($product->ID)
```

to get the permalink of the product

Where the `$product->ID` is the `postID`

Comment: I have a permalink that is :http://localhost/11New_plugin_Woo/?product=women-glasses3 ,and i want to display the product title of this permalink ,Do u have a clue , thanx

Comment: where you want to get this? on single.php ?

Comment: im working on a Wordpress plugin , when i use :  $product = get_page_by_title( 'Tshirt X', OBJECT, 'product' );
echo get_permalink( $product->ID ); it display the permalink of "Tshirt X" , so i want a way to do the inverse , (display product title by its given permalink) .

Comment: there is a option to get the `title` by id, then why you want to get it by permalinks?